# Acer Aspire 5552 screen drivers on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, acer-aspire

I've installed `Windows 10` to my `Acer Aspire 5552` but i'm having troubles with the drivers of the screen. It looks like it lacks of resolution or something.

I've already tried running *Windows Update* and nothing happened. I've also tried updating it from dispositives but nothing happened either as it says it's in its latter version as we can see in the pictures:

[image: Attempting to update screen drivers]

[image: Everything updated]

I've also tried downloading the drivers from [DriverScape](http://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/acer/laptops-desktops/aspire-5552/1432) but still the same.

I couldn't log into the [Acer Community Forum](http://community.acer.com/t5/English-Community/ct-p/en) because it throws me error so this is my last shot. Any ideas?

Comment: Windows 10 drivers do not exist for your mobile GPU.  You should immediately downgrade to Windows 7 and install the current display drivers on the support website for your laptop

Answer (score 0):

According to Acer Support Website. (Reference: https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/3276?b=1)
Your Acer Aspire 5552 only supports Windows 7 (32-bit) and Windows 7 (64-bit).

If you try to install Windows 10 on unsupported PC. It might be stable. Therefore, Windows 7 is recommended for this PC.

Your Acer also divided in 2 model, Aspire 5552 and Aspire 5552G. The best way to verify correct model of your PC is entering serial number to Acer Support website. (Reference: https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support)
But, Unfortunately, both models are only support Windows 7.